# I need a powershell script to send few thousands print job in a spooler

Tags: powershell, printing

I know that I can do

```
$myhelp = Get-Help -Detailed Get-WmiObject
Out-Printer -InputObject $myhelp
```

It will print the help page from `Get-WmiObject`. However, for testing purposes, I need a few thousands jobs in the spooler. How can I script that so that I can reproduce the same script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply repeat your `Out-Printer` statement a few thousand times:

```
$MyHelp = Get-Help Get-WmiObject -Detailed
1..3000 |ForEach-Object { Out-Printer -InputObject $MyHelp }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's was easy... I'm still to new with all that.